# The best X11 development guide?

Tags: xorg, development

I have no experience develop with X11.

I have once programming with Win32, MFC, DirectX, etc. So there must be a lot Microsoft stuff filled in my brain, and I want to train myself to convert the brain to X style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on how far down the rabbit hole you want to go. At the very bottom is [Xlib](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib-tutorial/) and [XCB](http://xcb.freedesktop.org/tutorial/), but most people never go any lower than [GTK+](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk-tutorial/2.90/) or [Qt](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/tutorial.html).